# How do I create a Lint rule that detects the usage of an "it" in lambda functions. in Intellij/Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin, lint

I am trying to add a lint rule that will not allow me to use the word "it" inside a lambda function.

I believe it is bad practise and makes the code unreadable.

I have tried to change the Local Variable naming convention in Editor -> Inspection to be

```
^(?!it)[a-z][A-Za-z\d].*
```

but this does not catch the "it" operator.

is this possible?

Comment: Since the default `it` parameter is a fundamental part of the language design, you are much better off getting used to it than fighting against it. However, I suspect you might be using it or see it be used when there are better options.

Comment: Oh I'm used to it alright, I'm too used to it. I am using it even when it makes my code worse, I want to limit my own use of it. And my team's.

Comment: There are more cases where it improves readability than where it hinders it. And you can still choose not to use it when it would. This would be like banning if/else because when is sometimes more readable.

Comment: @Tenfour04 

Do you have any example where using the ambiguous "it" would be more clear than a well-named variable?

Comment: Any filter on a collection or sequence. A specific name doesn’t add any meaning, but it adds more complexity to what you’re reading.